# Format number when using Calculation Functions tabulator

Tags: javascript, jquery, numbers, number-formatting, tabulator

Hi I am trying add some number format when sum column value in tabulator (format number for sum function in footer).

And this is what i try so far.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function formatNumber(num) {
    var str = num.toString().split('.');
    if (str[0].length >= 5) {
      str[0] = str[0].replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1,');
    }
    if (str[1] && str[1].length >= 4) {
      str[1] = str[1].replace(/(\d{3})/g, '$1 ');
    }
    return str.join('.');
  }

  function getSum(total, num) {
    return total + num;
  }

  var adultCalc = function(values, data, calcParams) {
    var totalcount = 0;
    var count = 0;

    data.forEach(function(data) {
      count = data.price * data.qty;
      totalcount += count;
    });

    return formatNumber(totalcount);
  }


  var tabledata = [{
      id: 1,
      name: "Item A",
      price: "1000",
      qty: "2000"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Item B",
      price: "8500",
      qty: "1500"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "Item C",
      price: "9100",
      qty: "2500"
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: "Item D",
      price: "950",
      qty: "1100"
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: "Item E",
      price: "2000",
      qty: "750"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "Item F",
      price: "2500",
      qty: "1000"
    }
  ];

  var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    height: 205,
    data: tabledata,
    layout: "fitColumns",
    columns: [{
        title: "Name",
        field: "name",
        width: 150
      },
      {
        title: "Price",
        field: "price",
        bottomCalc: adultCalc
      },
      {
        title: "Qty",
        field: "qty",
        bottomCalc: "sum"
      }
    ]
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.1.4/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.1.4/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>

<div id="example-table"></div>
```

The problem is, how to call the function for seperate the total value like my price column?

My `price` column is [Custom Calculation Function](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/column-calcs#func-builtin) from tabulator so i'm possible to call `formatNumber` function.

But the `qty` column is built in function.

Is it possible to call `formatNumber` function in built-in function from tabulator?

Or any idea for solve this problem?

You can check in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dianeryanto/oypdca81/) too

> Actually Happen is: `qty` total 8850
>
> Expected result : 8,850 like my `price` total, seperate by comma.

Comment: actually happen is the `qty` still like usual digit (8850) my expectation is (8,850). seperate by comma like my price total sir. @mplungjan

Comment: `tabulator.info/docs/4.1/format#format-builtin` it used for the row formatter sir, not for the sum format. what i' m looking for is sum format @mplungjan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are having is because you are storing the numeric values in your data as strings, if you take them out of quotation marks the maths will work correctly:

```
{
    id: 5,
    name: "Item E",
    price: "2000",
    qty: "750"
},
```

should be

```
{
    id: 5,
    name: "Item E",
    price: 2000,
    qty: 750
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Took a while to find a good solution and your formatNumber did not help me ;)

```
  {
    title: "Qty",
    field: "qty",
    formatter:"money", formatterParams:{ thousand:",", precision:false },
    bottomCalc: function(values, data, calcParams) { if (values && values.length) {
       var total = values.reduce((sum, x) => +sum + +x);
       return (""+total).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
    }}, //"sum",
  }
```

I also added commas to all the prices and qtys

Like this

---

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function formatNumber(num) {
    return ("" + num).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
  }

  function getSum(total, num) {
    return total + num;
  }

  var adultCalc = function(values, data, calcParams) {
    var totalcount = 0;
    var count = 0;
    var i = 0;
    data.forEach(function(data) {
      count = data.price * data.qty;
      totalcount += count;
      i++
    });
    return formatNumber(totalcount);
  }


  var tabledata = [{
      id: 1,
      name: "Item A",
      price: "1000",
      qty: "2000"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Item B",
      price: "8500",
      qty: "1500"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "Item C",
      price: "9100",
      qty: "2500"
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: "Item D",
      price: "950",
      qty: "1100"
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: "Item E",
      price: "2000",
      qty: "750"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "Item F",
      price: "2500",
      qty: "1000"
    }
  ];

  var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    height: 205,
    data: tabledata,
    layout: "fitColumns",
    columns: [{
        title: "Name",
        field: "name",
        width: 150
      },

      {
        title: "Price",
        field: "price",
        formatter: "money",
        formatterParams: {
          decimal: ".",
          thousand: ",",
          symbol: "$",
          symbolAfter: "p",
          precision: false,
        },
        bottomCalc: adultCalc
      },

      {
        title: "Qty",
        field: "qty",
        formatter: "money",
        formatterParams: {
          thousand: ",",
          precision: false
        },
        bottomCalc: function(values, data, calcParams) {
          if (values && values.length) {
            var total = values.reduce((sum, x) => +sum + +x);
            return formatNumber(total)
          }
        }, //"sum",
      }
    ]
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.1.4/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.1.4/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>

<div id="example-table"></div>
```